# How fix "Invalid ODBC handle" for sajdbc4 under Wildfly 20?

Tags: jdbc, wildfly, driver, classpath

I had Wildfly 10 running previously and have just upgraded to Wildfly 20 (under Ubuntu 20). My configuration from the past no longer works when it comes to getting the Sybase SQL Anywhere 17 sajdbc4 driver working.

A quick summary of what's going wrong is that I installed sajdbc4.jar and the supporting files in /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main/. I then ran a simple Java test app to confirm that it can connect to a test database and it works fine. I configured a driver and datasource in standalone.xml and run Wildfly with the following. When I Test Connection for the datasource it fails with "Invalid ODBC handle":

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main
sudo ./standalone.sh
```

Can anyone explain what I still need to do to get the sajdbc4 driver to work?

Here are detailed notes:

*** I used tar to install Wildfly 20 in:
/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final

*** Placed the Sybase Sql Anywhere 17 sajdbc4.jar and other supporting files in /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main

*** I have a simple Java app that tests the connection which I run with:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main

java -classpath .:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar sajdbc4DriverTest.java

This simple test app runs and dumps a database table so I conclude that everything I need to work is in /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main

*** Here is module.xml (in .sybase/main):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mydomain.sybase">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sajdbc4.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
  </dependencies>
  </module>
```

*** To test Wildfly I added the driver definition in standalaone.xml as:

```
<drivers>
    ...
    <driver name="sajdbc4" module="com.mydomain.sybase"/>
</drivers>
```

*** I then add the following datasource in standalaone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/TestDB" pool-name="TestDB" spy="true" tracking="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlanywhere:Host=192.168.1.89:11111,192.168.1.89:11112;ServerName=TestDB;</connection-url>
    <driver>sajdbc4</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>...</user-name>
        <password>...</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

*** I then run in /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main
sudo ./standalone.sh
```

At the top of the Terminal's log we see:

```
    ...
JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Note that the two exports were ignored!

*** If I then try to test the datasource connection (in the Admin console) we crash with:

```
...

    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no dbjdbc17 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
    ...
    
    ]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"
```

In an attempt to get around the "export failures" I modified standalone.config (everything after "# ADDED FOLLOWING HACK")

```
#
# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#

    if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
       JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
       JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
       # ADDED FOLLOWING HACK
       JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main -cp .:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar"
    else
       echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
    fi
```

*** Again I run in /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin

```
sudo ./standalone.sh
```

At the top of the Terminal's log we now see:

```
JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.library.path=/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main -cp .:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/mydomain/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
```

So that suggests that we now have the java.library.path and classpath as needed.

*** If I again try to test the datasource connection we now crash with:

...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid ODBC handle
at com.mydomain.sybase//sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver.makeODBCConnection(Native Method)
at com.mydomain.sybase//sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver.connect(IDriver.java:809)
at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
... 35 more

]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0047: Connection is not valid"

1. Why are the export LD_LIBRARY_PATH and export CLASSPATH being ignored? (I expect that is what's causing the "no dbjdbc17 in java.library.path" error).  How do I specify these to Wildfly?
2. Even when JAVA_OPTS shows the java.library.path and cp are set we still fail with "Invalid ODBC handle". This is very strange because my simple Java app test showed that when both java.library.path and cp are set to ./sybase/main "everything works". Note that the test app uses the same connection string I use in the  in standalone.xml.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to set up JDBC driver and your datasource in Wildfly administration console at http://localhost:9990/console/ ? Please check what you have there in Configuration -> Subsystem -> Datasources & Drivers. Except of that for MySQL I have following driver setting in standalone.xml: <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>

Comment: Hi Valdimir, Sorry for the delayed response. I interpreted the "0 Answers" on the incident list as meaning "no response at all"! I did use the console to set them up then I copied the XML to post here.  I think my driver is set up OK but there's something about the <datasource> that Wildfly doesn't like. The only interesting thing there is the connection string but that same string works fine in my simple Java test app. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be related to the fact that I was running Wildfly as a service and apparently my efforts above to set the java.library.path is failing. I know the reason for the error but I do not know how to set the path when running as a service.